# Custom schema with nested parent node in spark-xml

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-xml

I am pretty new to spark-xml and I am finding it difficult to prepare a custom schema for my Object. Request you all to help me. Below is what I have tried.

I am using Spark 1.4.7 and spark-xml version 0.3.5

Test.Java

```java
StructType customSchema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
    new StructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),

    DataTypes.createStructField("names", DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[]{
        DataTypes.createStructField("test", DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType),
            true)}), true)
});

final JavaRDD<Row> map = spoofRDD()
    .map(book -> RowFactory.create(
        book.getId(),
        book.getName(),
        book.getNames()));

final DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(map, customSchema);
df.show();
df.printSchema();



private JavaRDD<Book> spoofRDD() {

Book book1 = Book.builder().id("1").name("Name1")
    .names(new String[]{"1", "2"}).build();
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
books.add(book1);

return javaSparkContext.parallelize(books);
}
```

My POJO class Book.Java

```java
private final String id;
private final String name;
private final String[] names;
```

My **Expected** XML

```xml
<books>
<book>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Name1</name>
    **<parent>**
        <names>1</names>
        <names>2</names>
    **</parent>**
</book>
<book>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Name2</name>
    **<parent>**
        <names>1</names>
        <names>2</names>
    **</parent>**
</book>
```

So, as you see I wish to have a nested tag in the parent. How can I modify my customSchema to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct schema for the desired XML output is:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- parent: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- names: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)]
```

while your current schema is:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- names: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- test: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

So the only thing you have to change here is the name of the tag from `test` to `name` and `names` to `parent` and value type for the array contents.

```java
new StructType(new StructField[]{
  new StructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
  new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),

  DataTypes.createStructField("names", DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[]{
    DataTypes.createStructField("test", DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType),
        true)}), true)
})
```

The real problem is the data. Because `parent` has to be `struct`, `getNames` output should be wrapped with `Row`:

```java
.map(book -> RowFactory.create(
    book.getId(),
    book.getName(),
    RowFactory.create(book.getNames())));
```